# Unexpected child "generate" found under "flutter"

Tags: flutter

Cloning a [repo](https://github.com/flutter/gallery) and running command `pub get` throws this error:

> Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
>
> Unexpected child "generate" found under "flutter".
>
> Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\m3\repos\gallery\pubspec.yaml

[image: Screenshot]

### UPDATE

Running these commands [suggested](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/#running-flutter-gallery-on-flutters-master-channel) on repository, does NOT solve the error:

```sh
C:\Users\m3\repos\fork\gallery>C:\Users\m3\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.20.4-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat channel master

C:\Users\m3\repos\fork\gallery>C:\Users\m3\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.20.4-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat upgrade

C:\Users\m3\repos\fork\gallery>C:\Users\m3\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.20.4-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat channel stable

C:\Users\m3\repos\fork\gallery>C:\Users\m3\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.20.4-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat upgrade
```

Comment: What is your Flutter version? (Settings - Languages & Frameworks - Flutter, or `flutter --version` on the terminal)

Comment: @Nitrodon It is `flutter_windows_1.20.1-stable`

Comment: Also happens with `flutter_windows_1.20.4-stable` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error got resolved by running these two commands **only**:

```sh
C:\Users\m3\repos\fork\gallery>C:\Users\m3\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.20.4-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat channel master

C:\Users\m3\repos\fork\gallery>C:\Users\m3\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.20.4-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat upgrade
```

#### Note

Stay in `master` channel and do NOT return to `stable` channel, while you're working on this repository.

Comment: stable channel could not config like this?

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but I fixed it by upgrading flutter with `flutter upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your screenshot tells it all.
Where it says on your console "Please correct the **pubspec.yaml** file at", there looks like an issue you need to fix.

Go to the file, then run `pub get`. If you see any errors on console, then fix those errors. It's probably a syntax error or an indentation problem with your dependencies.

And also why do you have a `generate` tag under **pubspec**? Dart does not support the `generate` field (https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec).

Remove this field and you should be ok, assuming all the above have been addressed.

Comment: He have generate tag because he clone the official Flutter gallery example probably for learning purposes. It's not his fault that official example is nor working out of the box.

Comment: I'm not saying it is his fault. I did not mean to come out like that, lol. I just wanted to make it clear.

Comment: I also did not have bad intentions. Im more like disappointed by google or flutter team not by your response :) Take care my friend.